# Android: App crashes when selecting image from Samsung gallery (but it works with Google Photo app)

Tags: java, android

Good day,

The following code works when I select an image from the Google Photo app. However, when I select the same image from Samsung stock gallery, my app crashes.

I did some troubleshooting and realize the problem is with the **getContentResolver().query()**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        //Error happens when program try to run the following line of code
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);


        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: Try to see if getData() is returning null